# How do I match up email addresses and Facebook ids?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a users Facebook friend list and their email contacts and I want to match them together. The Facebook API doesn't help directly since the ability to pass in an e-mail address into the "user" search type was removed on July 10, 2013 and this search type only returns results that match a user's name (including alternate name).

Therefore, I need a more creative solution. Any other potential methods?

Answer (score 1):

You will not (and should not) be able to do this with the API. I've managed without any problems to find [your Facebook ID](https://facebook.com/510219880), so, by your logic, provided I have a friend of your's authenticated in my application, and your email address, I should be able to match your ID back to your email address. Once I have your email address I would be able to do lots and lots of spammy spammy things...

Retrieving email addresses for Facebook users can only be done by specifically and explicitly requesting the [email permissions from that specific user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) - and in that case, you already have their Facebook ID.

What you are trying to do here is to **bypass Facebook permissions**. The method you used to obtain users friend's email addresses was not through Facebook - **the Facebook user did not grant you access to their email address.** The fact that you obtained it (somehow) is irrelevant at this stage because without being able to *map the email back to the actual user* - you don't *really* know who it is.

Comment: Not sure why you down-voted my question. Services like Rapportive are still able to link emails and Facebook accounts. I am not sure how they do it but I've just tested it and somehow it still works. You mention spam, but I already have the names and email addresses so I'm not sure what extra "spam" knowing a UID will provide.

Comment: Not sure how you deduced that the downvote is mine - I'd suggest not accusing people before you have proof (and I assure you that you don't).

Comment: The fact that other services or companies are able to do this doesn't mean that they do so within the limits of Facebook's TOC. You should keep this in mind when trying to emulate or recreate some other applications functionality or company's service.

Comment: Lastly, spam is a relative term - what one user might consider spam would not be considered spam to the company that sent the email. At the end of the day, making the connection between a users Facebook account and their email is *extremely* valuable. You can get a lot of information about a user even from their public profile. The issue here is that targeted advertising comes into play.  From *your* public profile, I can see your musical interests, books you like, movies, games, groups and more - all this information is valuable to companies looking to send the right "spam" to the right user.

Comment: A random email address does have value - but an email address of someone you already know to be interested in your companies area of expertise is much much more valuable.